# access library functions in leiningen REPL

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, leiningen

For the development of a library I started from a lein project, invoked like so:

```
lein new mylib
```

if I call `lein install` now, I can access my library in other projects. But trying to immidiately test the functions I wrote failed:

```
lein repl
...
(dir mylib.core)
Exception No namespace: mylib.core found  clojure.core/the-ns (core.clj:4008)
```

Do I have to add something to the project.clj file maybe?

Comment: In which namespace is the REPL starting? I normally switch via `(in-ns NAME)`.

Comment: dir should also work from other namespaces. However, trying to (in-ns ..) evokes the same error mentioned above...

Comment: `in-ns` will give you a seemingly unusable repl if run before loading that namespace's code. `(clojure.core/refer-clojure)` will rescue the repl from that state btw.

Comment: Just to be sure: Your have a corresponding `(ns BLAH BLAH)` in your files? No typo there?

Answer (score 2):

In order to use a library you must cause the code to be loaded - that it be on the classpath is not sufficient.

You can do this easily in an `ns` declaration in a file of course, but in the repl it can be easier to use `(require '[my-lib.whatever :as w])` after which one can call `(w/foo)` `(w/bar)` etc. as expected. You can also use `(in-ns 'my-lib.whatever)` in order to switch to the namespace, but this will not give you a good result unless you have previously used `require` or `use` or `load-file` etc. to get the definitions first.

Comment: Interesting thing is that with Figwheel `(in-ns 'my-lib.whatever)` is all you need to do. See [here](https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel#using-the-clojurescript-repl).

Comment: This is because figwheel is preloading the ns for you. You can't guarantee that every config does this (and typos in the ns form can break this even when your config is right).

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you created a new library named `clj-foo`.

```
% lein new clj-foo
```

Start your repl.

```
% cd clj-foo
% lein repl
```

In the repl, load the main entry point to your library and switch to its namespace.

```
(load-file "src/clj_foo/core.clj")
(ns clj-foo.core)
```

Now you're in the `clj-foo.core` namespace, make sure to add back in the repl ns to get things like `doc` available.

```
(use 'clojure.repl)
```

That's it.  You're all set to start calling functions in your library.  Note that other library files will be available from the `clj-foo.core` namespace if they were loaded by namespace declaration at the top of `clj_foo/core.clj`.  If not, then you'll need to invoke `load-file` with their path as well.

If you make changes in `core.clj`.  You can invoke `load-file` again to pick up the new code.  As you progress, you can use cider to facilitate loading of individual functions and files.  But that's for another question.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a dependency to use your library from another project. To do this add a vector (a tuple-2) to the vector that is the value of the `:dependencies` key in the project.clj file. Here's an example:

```
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0"]
               [org.clojure/clojurescript "1.7.170"]
               [org.clojure/core.async "0.2.371"]
               [default-db-format "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"]
               [com.andrewmcveigh/cljs-time "0.3.14"]]
```

My own local library is called `default-db-format`. Its really no different to adding a dependency for `com.andrewmcveigh/cljs-time`.

As you say you can already do this, but are having trouble getting a REPL connection to the project of the library itself. When you go `(in-ns 'some-path)`, you need the single quote in front of `some-path`. Note that *some-path* is a different thing to the name of your library.

Rather than use `lein repl` you can use the figwheel repl - if your project is setup with figwheel. My library has only one entry point and that is `lein figwheel devcards`. After that I had no problem going to a namespace and trying out a function:

```
cljs.user=> (in-ns 'default-db-format.core)
nil
default-db-format.core=> (check 1 2)
```

As noisesmith mentioned having a REPL in your IDE is the best setup. No fiddly typing just bring up pre-configured REPLs (per namespace) with the click of a button (or keystroke). Figwheel/Cursive setup instructions [here](https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel/wiki/Running-figwheel-in-a-Cursive-Clojure-REPL).

Comment: unfortunately I keep getting the same error after adding my own lib to the dependencies as described in your example.

Comment: Yes - I don't really like/use `lein repl`. Answering this question before testing as usual! I'm investigating doing it with figwheel which also gives you a `repl`.

Comment: lein install works / doesn't give me errors. which it would, if there was something wrong with the dependencies. Figwheel is a cool thing, but rather for web development / or nodejs apps - at least I thought so.

Comment: My little library started off as a real library with no UI. But while 'doing the rounds' with boot and cljs.test etc I thought why not go back to what I know works. Even if your library doesn't have a UI your tests can (devcards rather than tests!).

Comment: Yeah, but that would be the best of course: having a repl that hot-reloads the library code whenever sth. changes.

Comment: In actual fact I did most of the development in Clojure and ported it across to cljs later. Just because I know there's a repl that works with Clojure. Now I might be comfortable enough starting off with cljs...

Comment: see my answer for how to get to files in libraries, for hot-reloading you can use `load-file` to load the namespace again from the file on disk regardless of how you initially loaded the ns, a good editor will map this to a keystroke

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue with the following configuration:

```
Leiningen 2.9.0 on Java 1.8.0_201 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
```

My file looks like this, and from the repl I desired to invoke the `foo` function

```
 (ns cljtest.test
  (:gen-class))

(defn foo [input]
  (assoc {} "a" 123))
```

Both these approaches worked fine for me on the repl.

1)Switch to the appropriate name space:

```
cljtest.core=> (in-ns 'cljtest.test)
#object[clojure.lang.Namespace 0x90175dd "cljtest.test"]
cljtest.test=> (foo nil)
{"a" 123}
cljtest.test=>
```

2)Require the appropriate name space:

```
cljtest.core=> (require '[cljtest.test :as test])
nil
cljtest.core=> (test/foo nil)
{"a" 123}
cljtest.core=>
```